# What does it mean to raise a complex number to a complex power?

Tags: complex-numbers

What does the formula $ (a+ib)^{x+iy}$ mean? All variables are real here, and $i $ represents $\sqrt {-1}$.

Comment: Is there any geometry behind this?

Comment: Just have a look at the [relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_complex_numbers)...

Comment: We yes of course.  Essentially you interpret $(a+ ib)^{iy} = e^{iy \log (a+ib)}$ (assuming you understand real powers so we ignore $x$). Riemann showed us how to think of $\log$ in the complex case as a mulit-valed function on the plane actually being a honest function on  a  Riemann Surface.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks.. But its principal logarithm only know??

Comment: $a+ib=R \times e^{i\varphi}$